What doe the Italian Phrase "basso i contamusse" mean attached to a persons photo
What does "basso i contamusse" mean when attached to a photo

Welcome to Italian.SE! Can you provide the context where you have found such expression?

Nothing, apparently. But if you give more context, it might help: perhaps it's a name of a person or place, or a regional phrase.

Is it really basso or is it abbasso?

It says: "down with liars" and it sounds quite exactly in Italian as well as in English. "Basso" means "down" with the meaning of "I/we are against that".
I can not figure out exactly which Italian dialect it is, but for sure it is one from North-Italy.

it is genovese https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mussa_(linguistica)

Ah... Genova! Strong people.

I'm confused: what do you mean by “it sounds quite exactly in Italian as well as in English”?

Sorry, my english is very poor.
What I wanted to say is that "down" has semantics that are very close to the one you can find in italian language.
Down = "basso" (in italian)
Both have a meaning (for "down") that expresses disappointment, hostility, dislike and so on.
In italy you can say "abbasso" and in english the same meaning can be obtained with "to down".
I said "it sounds" in place of "they have the same meaning/semantics". Not an happy choice...
